# User login blocked for insecure password into my hosted wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login, wordpress-admin

When I try to login into my wordpress admin account website, I can't. This happens just after I Move Wordpress from Local Server to Live Website.

When I try to get access to my website, i fail and I receive this mail in return:

"Access was denied because the password being used exists on lists of passwords leaked in data breaches. Attackers use such lists to break into sites and install malicious code. Please change or reset the password"

But the problem is worst because when I try to change my password, I get this message:

**Password recovery attempted**
"Someone tried to recover the password for user with email address: blablaemailadress.FR"

Then I realise I made a mistake when I suscribe to wordpress local because ** I put the wrong email adress instead of the good one** which is blablaemailadress.COM

After that I change my WordPress email  and password in the database phpmyadmin but even after the issue continue! I can't log into my admin website and I still continue to get the same mail which say to change my password and to "confirm" the new password with *still* the wrong e-mail adress...

IF someone can answear or have a similar problem, I will be glad to hear you

Answer (score 0):

To change the WordPress admin email address in PhpMyAdmin, you need to update it in both tables `_options` and `_users` (where _ is prefixed with your own prefix)

1. In `_options` the row for `option_name = admin_email` set the
   `option_value = yournewemail@example.com`
2. In `_users` the row for your account just replace the `user_email`

Answer (score 0):

Create new User by below code, then check old User detail in admin panel.

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
  
    $username = 'admin';
    $password = 'password';
    $email_address = 'webmaster@mydomain.com';

    if ( ! username_exists( $username ) ) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email_address );
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        $user->set_role( 'administrator' );
    }
    
} );
```